# Access denied exception accessing SQS Queue from EKS Pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk

Im trying to send message from a pod running in EKS to SQS Queue using the following code :

```
public void sendMessageToStandardQueue(String queueName, String message) {
    AmazonSQS sqsClient = buildSqsClient();
    SendMessageRequest sendMessageStandardQueue = new SendMessageRequest()
            .withQueueUrl(sqsClient.getQueueUrl(new GetQueueUrlRequest(queueName)).getQueueUrl())
            .withMessageBody(message);
    sqsClient.sendMessage(sendMessageStandardQueue);
}
```

It is working fine with the following pod permission :

```
   {
      "Sid": "AllowSQSAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:<Region>:<Id>:*"
    }
```

But when I change the pod permission to a specific queue instead of the entire region:

```
   {
      "Sid": "AllowSQSAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:<Region>:<Id>:<queue-name>"
    }
```

Iam getting the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The specified queue does not exist or you do not have access to it. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue
```

How can I resolve this Issue?